# A boundary point is a limit point of $M$ and $M^{c}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have been studying the basic concepts in topology and i'm wondering if i have a boundary point i can see it like a limit point of $M$ and $M^{c}$ where $M\subset X$ and $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s almost right: it’s a point $x$ that is in both the closure of $M$ and the closure of $X\setminus M$. Thus, every open nbhd of $x$ intersects both $M$ and $X\setminus M$, but $x$ need not actually be a **limit** point of both of them. For instance, $2$ is a boundary point of $M=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, but it isn’t a limit point of $M$: it’s in the closure of $M$ simply because it’s in $M$. (However, it’s in the closure of $\Bbb R\setminus M$ because it really is a limit point of that set.)

If $X$ is a metric space, though, you can say that a point $x$ is in the boundary of $M$ if and only if there are sequences in both $M$ and $X\setminus M$ that converge to $x$, so long as you bear in mind that one of those sequences may be constant at $x$.